# Excel formula If cell (that has date and time) contains a range of time, display return value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a column of date and time fields (e.g. "15/6/2021  11:35:22 PM"). I would like to display "Morning" if the field consists of time between 06:00:00 and 11:59:59 and display "Afternoon" if the field consists of time between 12:00:00 and 18:00:00.

I tried this but doesn't work:
[image]

Is there any **excel** formula that can do this?

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: please post the formula as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time has a date so it will not be between two times with no date.  Date/Time in excel is a double.  With the date as an integer and time being a decimal.  to compare times you need to strip the integer:

```
=IF(MOD(A1,1)<TIME(12,0,0),"Morning","Afternoon")
```

[image]

for just 6am to 6pm:

```
=IF(OR(A1-INT(A1)<0.25,A1-INT(A1)>0.75),"N/A",IF(A1-INT(A1)<0.5,"Morning","Afternoon"))
```

[image]

Comment: @ellie it probably is a floating point error.  You can try `A1-INT(A1)` instead of the `MOD(A1,1)` and see if that works better.

Comment: what if I want "NA" to be displayed when time is not between 6am to 6pm? :)

Comment: Then you need to nest IFs:  `=IF(OR(A1-INT(A1)<.25,A1-INT(A1)>.75),"N/A",IF(A1-INT(A1<.5,"Morning","Afternoon"))` .25 = 6 am. .75 = 6 pm and .5 = noon.

Comment: sorry, if its 6am to 11:59am "morning", if 12pm to 6pm then display "afternoon", else display "NA". how do I get this?

Comment: thanks so much Scott!! :) have a great day/evening wherever you are